# Options to avoid executing code on __debug__

Tags: python

### Code

Let us define a `debug` function, that is used for debugging purposes:

```
def debug(x):
    print(x)
    return True
```

This function is fast. However, sometimes, the parameter that is evaluated when calling `debug` is slow to process:

```
def slow_processing(x):
    time.sleep(x)
    return 'Now!'
```

So, basically, in our code, we could see lines like this one:

```
[...]
debug(slow_processing(1))
[...]
```

### Problem

I would like to avoid executing `debug` and evaluating its arguments when `__debug__ == True`. This means I could do this:

```
if __debug__:
    debug(slow_processing(1))
```

Or even this, which is a bit shorter:

```
assert debug(slow_processing(1))
```

And the code would not be executed, nor its parameters evaluated when running Python with the `-O` option.

### Question

This, however, would require to modify code on each call in the source code. I was wondering if there was a way in Python (which has sometimes surprised me with its magic) to declare the function in a way that is not executed and its parameters are not evaluated when `__debug__ == True` but without having to modify the source code for each call of `debug`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to prevent evaluation of the parameters if the code containing the call is executed.

Your best bet in this case might be to change both the calls to debug and the definition of the function and make it take a function as its first parameter:

```
def debug(fn, *args, **kw):
    if __debug__:
        print(fn(*args, **kw))
    return True
```

Then you call it:

```
debug(slow_processing, 1)
```

Comment: Your workaround implies modifying the source code for each call of `debug` (so I would rather simply put an `assert`). However "There is no way" is a valid answer to my question (it seems no-one else could prove otherwise). So thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is actually possible. To reduce the changes in your code, I would use a one-liner like

```
__debug__ and debug(slow_processing(1))
```

But Duncan's answer is a better solution !